# How to enable Azure "Daily anomaly by resource group" alert using ARM template?

Tags: azure, infrastructure-as-code, azure-alerts, azure-cost-calculation

I have *Anomaly Cost Detection* alert created in Azure Subscription -> Cost Management -> Cost Alerts. The alert was created manually via Azure Portal.
As I have created an ARM template that will deploy few other "standard Azure Monitor" alerts upon creation of Azure Subscription, I want to find a way to enable/disable this alert using ARM template so that I can include it in the list.

What I understood is that the alert is extension and cannot exist as a resource by itself, and the documentation states that needs to be attached to other resource. Does anyone have an idea to which one? Also, the documentation states "*To create a Microsoft.CostManagement/alerts resource, add the following JSON to your template.*", can anyone suggest a template where I can indeed add this resource?
MS Docs Link:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.costmanagement/2019-11-01/alerts?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: The Microsoft.CostManagement/alerts resource needs to be associated with the Azure Subscription or Resource Group that it monitors. In an ARM template, you should incorporate the alerts resource within the same template as the subscription or resource group definition, adhering to the JSON structure outlined in the Microsoft documentation link referenced. @Sasha

Comment: Thanks Vinay. Anyway, it seems to me that your answer does not say much more than what is on the documentation link itself. Can you provide example with actual template of how you'll incorporate that alert? As it certainly is not the same as "incorporating" other resources, such as locks, which actually have shared template structure that can be attached to, for example, storage account.

Answer (score 0):

> **Effective plan for Cost Alert Management with ARM Templates**

To create a `Microsoft.CostManagement/alerts` resource for the test purpose, I fetch the template snapshot from my resource group.

[image]

You’ll need to add the following snippet to your ARM template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.CostManagement/alerts",
            "apiVersion": "2022-10-05-preview",
            "name": "MyAnomalyAlert",
            "existing": {
                "name": "vinay-rg" 
            },
            "properties": {                         
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Replace the alert name and resource group name from the that associate with the alert.

The  `"properties"`  section allows you to configure the alert further. You can specify properties such as thresholds, frequency, and actions to take when the alert triggers.

Save the template with alerts as `azuredeploy.json`

now run the commands

```
az deployment group create --resource-group vinay-rg --template-file azuredeploy.json
```

Once the deployment is successful, navigate to the Azure portal Go to the resource group where you deployed the template Verify that the **Cost Management alert** is associated with the specified resource group.

***Reference:***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.costmanagement/alerts?pivots=deployment-language-terraform

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/resource-manager-alerts-log?tabs=json